# Autocompletion for VSCode for a module imported via <script src>

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, processing

## Issue description

I would like to have Visual Studio Code to hint autocompletion and provide documentation for a JavaScript project which includes <s>libraries</s> *a module* in a separate HTML file.

## Context

I am using [P5JS](https://p5js.org/). It assumes we include the P5JS library and our script via the `<script src="…">` tag in an HTML file. Autocompletion and documentation work after installing the [p5.vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samplavigne.p5-vscode). So, no problem here.

I am also using [`ml-matrix`](https://github.com/mljs/matrix), which I'm including in the HTML via the `<script src="…">` tag. The library constructors and methods can be accessed via `mlMatrix.`. *(I figured this by toying around in the console, and I wouldn't know otherwise how to find out I need to prepend `mlMatrix.` to all functions in the library.)*

`index.html`

```html
<head>
    <!-- script src="…" P5JS libraries -->
    <script src="./node_modules/ml-matrix/matrix.umd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

`script.js`

```js
A = mlMatrix.Matrix.eye(3)  // no autocompletion or docs, code runs
console.log(A)
```

## Workaround

Adding `import * as mlMatrix from "ml-matrix"` to the beginning of `script.js` makes autocompletion and documentation work, but the overall project does not run. So, I have to comment and uncomment the first line every time I save and preview my edits on the browser.

`script.js`

```js
import * as mlMatrix from "ml-matrix"

A = mlMatrix.Matrix.eye(3)  // autocompletion and docs work, code doesn't run
console.log(A)
```

When loading the HTML, the browser complains with `script.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.`.

## Desiderata

I'd like to be able to save and preview my project while having a working autocompletion and documentation hint from VSC.

---

## Debugging

After reading a few sections of David Flanagan's «JavaScript: The Definitive Guide», I started figuring out what's going on. So, I'm reporting here my current understanding.

JavaScript, or rather ECMAScript, used to be a scripting language.
*Scripts* loaded with `<script src="…">` are "global" scripts, living on the current page, injecting `var`s and `function`s in the global scope (or `window` object).

In order to support proper software engineering relying on modularity, *modules* were introduced in 2015, in ECMAScript 6, or ES6 in short. To import a module in an HTML document one can use `<script type="module" src="…">`.

Now, to import a module in a JS file, the file itself needs to be a module. So, dealing with an actual script myself, I cannot do such a thing.

Even by `<script src="…">` a module, it won't inject itself in the main namespace. It will create a whatever name where it will store everything it exports. So, now we are at the point where we need to instruct the IDE that a module has been loaded on the HTML side with a specific name and it's used in a JS script.

So, we have now a more articulate question.

## Issue re-statement

How to inform VSC that a module has been loaded through the HTML page?

I believe a probable answer will include some custom `jsconfig.json` to be created. Right now I have zero clues about how to do this.

Another solution would be using some specific `///<reference path="…"/>` at the beginning of the JS file. Also for this I have no specific knowledge.

Comment: Any hint someone could spare? I really don't know where to turn to…